# Find the point in $S=\{(x, y)| x, y \text{ are positive integers }\}$ which have the least possible distance sum from the points $(0,12)$ and $(8,0).$

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Let $S=\{(x, y)| x, y \text{ are positive integers }\}$ viewed as a subset of the plane. For every point $P$ in $S,$ let $d_P$ denote the sum of the distances from $P$ to the point $(8,0)$ and the point $(0,12).$ Show that the number of points $P$ in $S$ such that $d_P$ is the least among all elements in the set $S,$ is $3.$

My attempt:

If $(x,y)\in S$ then, $d_P=\sqrt{x-8)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y-12)^2}.$

If we were to minimize $d_P$ then we must minimize $$\left(\sqrt{(x-8)^2+y^2} \right )^2+\left(\sqrt{x^2+(y-12)^2} \right)^2,$$ as $\sqrt{(x-8)^2+y^2},\sqrt{x^2+(y-12)^2},$ are after all, positive integers.

We define, a function $$f(x,y)=(x-8)^2+y^2+x^2+(y-12)^2 ,$$ and observe, that $f(x,y)\geq 0,\forall (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2(\text{or better, S}).$

But I don't understand how to find the least possible value of the (double variable) function $f$ in it's range. I think some calculus is needed to find the local minima (, if any) of this function. But then again, I don't know multivariable calculus, as I studied only single variable calculus up until now. So, possibly, I dont know how maxima/minima works in the so called, "Multivariable Calculus". (Finally, is there at all any other way to solve this problem in a simpler manner? )

Comment: Just from geometry, you get the integer points on the line segment between these points, as they exist. It is a different situation when such do not exist, like when the first point were $(0,11)$

Comment: @LutzLehmann Nice observation! I never thought about this really. So, then we need to consider all the points, in the straight line, $(8,0)$ and $(0,12)$, and the answer might be the midpoint of the two given points, so as to make the distance minimum, in an optimal way. So, the required point is, $(4,6)$. But in the question, it claims three such points, do exist. So, that's strange.

Comment: @DanielSchepler But according to the definition of the set $S$, $(x,y)$ should be positive. But $0$ is not a positive integer.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Interesting question what happens if you repeat the question with $(m, 0)$ and $(0, n)$ where $\gcd(m, n) = 1$.  In all the cases I've tried (which includes all cases where $m, n \le 100$), the minimizing point seems to be also the point at minimum distance from the line, i.e. $(i, j)$ where $| ni + mj - mn | = 1$.  Even though looking at the corresponding ellipses, you would think in some cases being closer to the midpoint could counterbalance being farther from the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be evaluated graphically using the triangle inequality.

[image]

Consider the line joining $(0,12)$ and $(8,0)$. Clearly, the sum of distances from the fixed point is minimum and equal to the length of the line segment if it lies on the line (by triangle inequality).
For verification, you may draw a point away from this line and you will see that the sum of distances is always greater than the 3rd side length.
Finding the equation of the line we get,
$$3x + 2y = 24$$
Clearly, this has 3 integral solutions which arise when x is some even number in the interval $(0, 8)$.
For reference, the values are
$$x = 2$$
$$x = 4$$
$$x = 6$$
Thus there are 3 points satisfying the given condition.

Comment: But how do you know, whether those three points, on the line segment have the minum sum of distances or not ?

Comment: Because they lie on the same line segment, the sum of distances is basically the length of the line segment itself.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it clearer

Comment: Ok, so the thing is that, those three are the only integral points on the straight line, that lies on/in the triangle , correct ?

Comment: Yes you got it!